# Blender 2.8 - i want "Material" view back

Tags: 3d-view, interface

100% of my work time i had in 2.78-2.79 was in Material view, with all textures, lighting (simplified), shadows, etc.

In 2.80 i see only wireframe/bad solid/stupid solid/render view.

How to get back Material view exactly the same it was before?

Comment: It will never come back (code was thrown into the trash can). Try to adjust the viewport shading...

Comment: @JacekSawicki your question is hilarious but you should explain why Look-Dev Mode (which is a studio-lit render preview) or the realtime render mode aren't cutting it for your use case. If it looks ugly, maybe your scene is just ugly? :P (just teasing) Are some features of your materials not rendering correctly in either mode?  If computation time is the issue, note that Eevee provides smoother feedback almost instantaneously compared to Cycles (although the shadows aren't as detailed and some shaders are incompatible). I would use Eevee for visualization but do my actual renders in Cycles.

Comment: I am sympathetic that your scene is not looking how you expect because I had similar issues for a long time with, lighting rendering and color matching.

Answer (score 4):

You should get similar results when you select the *Look Dev mode* and enable *Scene Lights* and *Scene World* which will take your world settings and the lights in your scene into consideration.

[image]

Comment: Nope, not even close. Bad lights, unrealistic shadows and many more flaws.

Comment: @JacekSwicki The shadows etc. weren't accurate in the 2.79 material mode either, they were just GLSL shader. If you want the path traced / rendered preview, you need to select the one next to it. Perhaps you can add screenshots of what specific effects you're missing in 2.8 or what is supposedly worse in comparison with 2.79?

Comment: @JacekSawicki   LookDev also allows you to customize lights, HDRI.. under the settings cog in the Viewport Shading panel ...

Comment: https://ibb.co/PskSLLG

As i said - not even close.

I don't want rendered view - it's too slow and limited for working.

Comment: @JacekSawicki there will be some configuration that causes a green and grey tint. Just by looking at your image it's hard to say what the cause is. If you can upload your project and add the link to your question, we could take a closer look and recommend changes. (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)